# How to make intent to specify user's location?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an android app where user clicks a specific button I want the app to specify the user's location and the user must confirm that location. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a)